# changing values of a boolean field

Tags: java, testing, boolean

I have a custom class as shown below:

```
public class A{
  private String msg,
  private String name,
  private int number;
  private boolean isActive;
}
```

I am writing a testcase where I can creating an instance of this class

```
A case = new A("This is an sample", "Raks", 1, true);
//some logic here...
//
//

//-- Now i want to change the activity of case to false.
//case.isActive ==false; // This does not work, but I want to achieve this.

//I was not able to do it, and hence created another instance
A case2 = new A("This is an sample", "Raks", 1, false);
```

I wanted to know if the value of a field can be changed directly instead of creating a new instance.

-------------------------------EDIT-------------------

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public class A{
  private String msg,
  private String name,
  private int number;
  private boolean isActive;
}
```

Comment: You can change it with a public setter method

Comment: Create a setter to change the field - kind of the point of encapsulation

Comment: ok, so the values to the fields in A, comes from a remote server, and hence there is no setter. I am simulating a scenario where A is active initially and then goes inactive.

Comment: Does that mean you don't want to/can't change the class to add a setter? Would the simulated situation involve 2 messages in a real scenario? If so, I'd use 2 messages as that seems what would happen if there are any changes in the remote server.

Comment: i cannot add a setter, analogy would be something like an alarm, it is active first and then gets inactive.

Answer (score 4):

Create a public setter method

```
public class A{
  private String msg,
  private String name,
  private int number;
  private boolean isActive;

  public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
    this. isActive = isActive;
  }
}
```

You can call the setter from the test case since it's public.

```
case.setIsActive(false);
```

Comment: Thanks Pabasara, But the catch here is, for my requirement I do not have a setter.. The values come from a remote server. I am simulating a scenario where initially the case is active and then turns inactive.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. You are not the one creating the class A? Can you post the complete code?

Comment: I updated the class, The concept is something like an Alarm, initially it will be active and then it goes inactive. I just have a getter because these values cannot be modified. However, for testing purposes, I am simulating a inactivity